# Definir fuso horário para todo o projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, datetime, timezone

Recentemente hospedei uma aplicação em um servidor norte-americano, com isso as datas estão fora do fuso horário brasileiro. Dessa forma, gostaria de saber se existe um meio de definir o fuso horário uma única vez para que toda vez que for utilizado o `DateTime.Now` em uma variável, seu valor já venha atualizado conforme o fuso definido.

Outra coisa também, gostaria de saber se é possível definir uma única vez o formato brasileiro para todas as datas, sem ter que sair alterando o formato em cada variável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível. Nem sei se é desejável. Horários costumam funcionar melhor como UTC na maioria das situações e só serem apresentados ou manipulados em situações específicas como *timezone*.

O que pode fazer para facilitar um pouco é criar uma classe utilitária com métodos (possivelmente de extensão) que já te devolvam os horário no *timezone* desejado (você manteria nessa classe utilitária uma propriedade estática indicando qual é o *timezone* que deseja e os métodos respeitariam isso sem precisar passar um argumento dizendo qual usar, ainda que possa permitir opcionalmente ter um parâmetro para escolher um diferente do padrão ativo.

A apresentação das datas, não o fuso, podem ser feitas de acordo com a configuração da cultura. Tem algumas formas. Por código é usado:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/Global.cs).

Comment: Puts, que pena. Já para o formato eu adicionei isso no web.config: <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" /> e deu certo.

Comment: Para formato sim, mas fuso não tem jeito.