# Trocar formato da data no servidor C# / Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema muito chato, Eu estou pegando um `DataDeCadastro` do servidor que esta em `DateTime` quando a data bem ele está na versão dos Estados Unidos `("dd/MM/yyyy")`  eu uso o `.ToString()` para formatar da forma que eu quero.

Eu tenho um forma de edição em que a pessoa pode mudar a data de cadastro, mas quando eu tento enviar para o servidor ele inverte o dia com o mês, não sei com lidar com essa situação , eu tentei inverter novamente com o ToString e atribuir a um `DateTime` mas da erro quando o mês é maior que 12.

Meu Controller é esse :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult Editar(string Titulo, string Descricao, DateTime DataCadastro, int ProdutoId)
    {
        int idProduto = Convert.ToInt32(ProdutoId);
        var produto = ProdutoServico.GetById(idProduto);
        if (Titulo != null && Descricao != null && DataCadastro != null )
        {

            produto.Descricao = Descricao;
            produto.DataCadastro = DataCadastro;
            produto.Titulo = Titulo;
            ProdutoServico.Update(produto);
            if (produto.CategoriaProdutoId == null)
            {
                return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Produto", new {CategoriaId = 0, area = "Lojista" }), isRedirect = true });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Produto", new { CategoriaId = produto.CategoriaProdutoId.Value, area = "Lojista" }), isRedirect = true });
            }
        }
        return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Produto", new { CategoriaId = produto.CategoriaProdutoId.Value, area = "Lojista" }), isRedirect = true });
    }
```

nesse controller a data chega correta  exemplo : `30/09/2016`  mas ele depois que salva ele tenta salvar assim: `09/30/2016`  não sei como resolver isso.

lembrando que o servidor esta nos EUA, muito Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer gravar ela como pt-br no banco ou exibir como pt-br?

Comment: Usar `ToString` pra formatar é um baita problema, hein.

Comment: a data não tem formato, a apresentação é que tem. Tem que gerar o texto que deseja ou fazer a aplicação interpretar desta forma sempre: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141232/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121440/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136014/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118450/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68247/101

Comment: Então o problema e que na hora de de salvar eu confiro o 'DateTime' e ta certo , exemplo 'Mounth = 9   e'  Day = 11'   Mas quando salva ele ele da erro.

Comment: o Globalization no web config resolveu meu problema , vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar de diversas formas:
Forçar programaticamente a cultura da data a ser exibida com o seguinte trecho:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo brasil = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
String dataBr = DateTime.Now.ToString(brasil);
```

Ou especificar no seu arquivo Web.config a cultura a ser utilizada:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: O do Web config resolveu meu problema obrigado.